# How to browse files and show its content by clicking buttons in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, html, css, laravel-5.3

How can I browse the files inside my folder by clicking `Next` button and `Previous` button then show the file contents inside a table cell?

**Here's my sample output but sadly its not working to me:**

[Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Druj8.jpg)

**Here's the code I used:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Browse Files</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dir = '/xampp/htdocs/files';
$file = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));

function showContent($fdata) {
    $fopen = fopen($fdata,'r') or die ("Could not open file");
    $content = fread($fopen,filesize($fdata)) or die("Could not read the file");
    echo $content;
    fclose($fopen);
}
  ?>
<table border = "1" cellpadding = "10" align = "center" width = "500">
    <frame method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>File Contents: </h3> <br />
                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
                        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file); $i++) {
                            $path = $dir ."/". $file[$i];
                            showContent($path);
                        }   
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['previous'])) {
                        for($x = sizeof($file); $x > sizeof($file); $i--) {
                            $path = $dir ."/". $file[$i];
                            showContent($path);
                        }   
                    }
                ?>      
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td align = "center">
                <input type = "submit" name = "previous" value = "Previous">
                <input type = "submit" name = "next" value = "Next">
            </td>
    </frame>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really think of any way to do it besides getting the contents of the folder first:

```
# You want to feed in the base directory, the current file path, and whether
# to advance or previous
function getContents($dir,$current = false,$advance = false)
{
    # You don't want to get the file contents of images, it's garbled
    $img        =   ['gif','jpg','jpeg','png'];
    # Get the contents of the folder and remove directories and dots
    $contents   =   array_values(array_filter(scandir($dir),function($v) use ($dir){
        if(in_array($v,['.','..']))
            return false;

        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$v))
            return false;

        return true;
    }));
    # If no current file, grab the first one
    if(empty($current)) {
        if(!empty($contents)) {
            $nPath  =   array_shift($contents);
            $next   =   $dir.'/'.$nPath;                
            return [
                'img' => (is_file($next) && in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($next,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),$img)),
                'file' => (is_file($next))? basename($next) : false,
                'current'=> (!empty($nPath))? $next : false,
                'data'=>(!empty($nPath) && is_file($next))? file_get_contents($next) : false
            ];
        }
    }
    else {
        # If there is a current file being viewed..
        foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
            # See if this file is the file being viewed
            if($dir.'/'.$value == $current) {
                # If want to see next, get the next key
                if($advance == 'next')
                    $nPath  =   (!empty($contents[$key+1]))? $contents[$key+1] : $contents[0];
                # Rewind the current array
                else {
                    prev($contents);
                    prev($contents);
                    $nPath  =   (!empty($contents[key($contents)]))? $contents[key($contents)] : $contents[$key];
                }
                $next   =   $dir.'/'.$nPath;                
                return [
                    'img' => (is_file($next) && in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($next,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),$img)),
                    'file' => (is_file($next))? basename($next) : false,
                    'current'=>$next,
                    'data'=>(!empty($nPath) && is_file($next))? file_get_contents($next) : false
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
# Set the action
$action     =   (!empty($_POST['action']))? strtolower($_POST['action']) : false;
# Capture current path
$curr       =   (!empty($_POST['current']))? $_POST['current'] : false;
# Retrieve the next or prev
$contents   =   getContents(__DIR__,$curr,$action);
?>
<table border = "1" cellpadding = "10" align = "center" width = "500">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>File Contents: <?php echo $contents['file'] ?></h3> <br />
                <?php if(!empty($contents['img'])): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$contents['current']) ?>" style="max-width: 100px;" />
                <?php else: ?>
                <pre><?php echo htmlspecialchars($contents['data']) ?></pre>
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td align = "center">
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="current" value="<?php echo $contents['current'] ?>" />
                    <input type = "submit" name="action" value = "Previous">
                    <input type = "submit" name="action" value = "Next">
                </form>
            </td>
    </frame>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You probably have to finesse this a bit, but it's pretty close...I don't know how efficient it is though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I appreciate it and BTW, Happy New Year :) I tried your code above but I'm having a problem when I click the Previous button - when I clicked it the table cell was blank or I received an "Unidentified Error".

Comment: Yeah for me, there was a spot that required more troubleshooting.It worked but when it gets to the end of the directory it has an issue. I was able to do next or previous except when it hit that spot. I could probably troubleshoot it, but what I have should be the bulk of the work.

Comment: :P hehe, I understand and thanks for the help :) I'll experiment it later, maybe this is a personal question but related to the code above, **where can I learn this part because honestly I'm just a newbie:**

`$contents   =   array_values(array_filter(scandir($dir),function($v) use ($dir){
        if(in_array($v,['.','..']))
            return false;

        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$v))
            return false;

        return true;
    }));`

Comment: I updated the one line that should remove the undefined index. The only issue now is when you get to the end of the directory contents, it will still go blank, but that is just another line that has to be fiddled with to fix that. Which part are you wanting clarity with?

Comment: **Also this one:**
`return [
                    'img' => (is_file($next) && in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($next,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),$img)),
                    'file' => (is_file($next))? basename($next) : false,
                    'current'=>$next,
                    'data'=>(!empty($nPath) && is_file($next))? file_get_contents($next) : false
                ];`

Comment: What do you want to know about those lines?

Comment: in your code above its ok to insert a function inside an array function? 

array_values(array_filter(scandir($dir),**function($v) use ($dir)**

Comment: Yeah, you can use an actual function that you previously defined in your script or, if you don't really need to use the function again except for this one time, you can make an *anonymous* function instead. Not all native PHP functions accept anonymous functions, but a lot do. The `use($var)` from that line allows you to insert content into your function that has been defined before the anonymous function is called otherwise you can't access custom content.

Comment: Incidentally, I fixed the other issue. It should now start over when it gets to the end.

Comment: I should also note, when you are looking on the php site for how to use functions and stuff, you can see if the function accepts functions, generally it says `callable $callback` in the description like: `array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] )`.

Comment: Thank you again for the great reply :) How about this one:
**return** `return[ 'img' => (is_file($next) && in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($next,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),$img‌​)), 'file' => (is_file($next))? basename($next) : false, 'current'=>$next, 'data'=>(!empty($nPath) && is_file($next))? file_get_contents($next) : false ];`

It's ok to return a value with that kind of format? Because I get used to apply return statement in this format: **return $var; or return 0; or return 1; in C/C++?** hehe, sorry for the noob question, BTW, my target file is only for text file not images.

Comment: Yeah, what it's returning is an array and the values of the array are set dynamically, so i could have done: `$arrImg = (is_file($next) && in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($next,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),$img‌​‌​)); $nextFile = (is_file($next))? basename($next) : false; $useData = (!empty($nPath) && is_file($next))? file_get_contents($next) : false; return ['img'=>$arrImg,'file'=>$nextFile,'current'=>$next,'data'=>$useData];`

Comment: Thanks again :) I'm just curious why this code of mine is not working?
`if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
                        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file); $i++) {
                            $path = $dir ."/". $file[$i];
                            showContent($path);
                        }   
                    }`
**Even I try a simple code like this its not working?**

`if (isset($_POST['next'])) { echo "Success clicking next button"; }`